# Attach to service process SecurityHealthService from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, windows-11, windows-security

I my trying to attach to the SecurityHealthService.exe process from VS 2022

[image: Task Manager]

However it doesn't show up in the "Attach to Process" dialog

[image: VS 2022]

I'm having an issue enabling Memory Integrity in Core Isolation, and pressing Scan shows CPU activity for SecurityHealthService.exe in Task Manager, but not for SecurityHealthHost.exe

[image: Core Isolation]

The incompatible drivers list is blank

[image: Core Isolation]

- All reported drivers in Autoruns are verified

  - Removed empty WinSetupMon and Adobe Type Manager entries and rebooted
- Cannot find any log entries in Computer Management
- Virtualization Enabled
- SMM Security Mitigation On

Therefore, I want to attach to SecurityHealthService.exe and look for any strings.

[image: Autoruns]

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Explorer (procexp.exe) from Windows Internals site to examine strings.

If you can't attach to the process, it is probably because you are not running your instance of Visual Studio as an administrator. Run it as an adminstrator and you should be able to attach to the process.

I right click on the shortcut and select my Visual Studio version and it allows an option to run as administrator.

Of course, you must have administrator privileges to do so.

[image]